# IcedTea and lwgjl

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, lwjgl, icedtea

I have recently found myself on a Linux computer and am liking it so far.

However, I have been having an issue and dont really know the source. I am trying to make a java project that uses lwjgl in eclipse (something I have done in windows) but when I run the code my display window comes up black and blinking and I get this error report-

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f5004c70c98, pid=10427, tid=139981673781008
#
# JRE version: 6.0_18-b18
# Java VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (16.0-b13 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Derivative: IcedTea6 1.8.1
# Distribution: Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, package 6b18-1.8.1-0ubuntu1
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libX11.so.6+0x37c98]  XQueryExtension+0x28
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/jeff/workspace/SpinDodge3/hs_err_pid10427.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please include
# instructions how to reproduce the bug and visit:
#   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/
#
```

I have the sun java 6 jdk installed and I have tried pointing eclipse to that using the -vm command but this error is the same. Java projects not using lwjgl work. Is this because I am using lwjgl wrong, the way it interacts with icedTea (something which the -vm command seems to do nothing for), eclipse? I have no idea where to even start.

Has anybody here used lwgjl in Linux, do they have any ideas?

Thankyou

(also I can post the error log but it is pretty long, I dont know how much help it will be)

EDIT: After I changed the jdk in use it runs but only for one frame and then crashes with this error-

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007fbfd4fb7c98, pid=2060, tid=140461906126608
#
# JRE version: 6.0_20-b02
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (16.3-b01 mixed mode linux-amd64 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libX11.so.6+0x37c98]  XQueryExtension+0x28
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /home/jeff/workspace/SpinDodge3/hs_err_pid2060.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
#
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell this is an error with eclipse and openGL in Ubuntu 10.04. It happens regardless of the jdk used (I have tried both). However, I have figured out that this error is only thrown when the program closes and was not causing the problems I saw with the lwjgl rendering. Except for the build-up of error logs just ignoring this error has caused me no problems so far.

Answer (score 1):

Run `sudo update-java-alternatives -l` to see the different versions of Java on your system. Then run `sun update-java-alternatives -s [java type]` to set it as the default, which binds it to the commands `java`, `javaw`, etc.

In your case, you should run **`sudo update-java-alternatives -s java-6-sun`** as mentioned on the [Java Community Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Java) page.

---

Well it looks like Java isn't the problem. You should read about [SIGSEGV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGSEGV) and [XQueryExtension](http://www.tigr.net/afterstep/X/xlib/appendix/c/XQueryExtension.html); it looks like your Xlib or X11 is to blame.

If I were you, at this time I would follow the instructions; go to https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/openjdk-6/ and submit a bug report, paste this error and attach the logfile (`/home/jeff/workspace/SpinDodge3/hs_err_pid10427.log`). See if the experts can redirect you to exactly where the problem lies.

Also, of course, make sure your system is updated. You don't want to report a bug that has already been fixed.

Comment: Yes this worked (actually it turned out I only had the sun Java 6 jre but it was easy to get the jdk)! Thank you so much, this way I didst have to go through the hassle of removing the openJDK.

Comment: sudo update-alternatives --config java    is what ended up working, found on the link you posted.

Comment: Oh man I am so sorry, I thought this worked (it seemed to at first). It did change my version of java but I am still getting an error.

Answer (score 0):

You are not executing with the Sun JVM but with the OpenJDK, and there are subtle differences.  Switch Ubuntu to use the Sun JVM  and try again.

Comment: Ok, thats what I was trying to do with the Eclipse -vm option but obviously that did nothing (I have both installed currently because chromium needs the Sun JVM as well).
After work today I will try removing the OpenJDK all together so there can be no confusion and report back.
Thankyou in advance!